# The command "go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo" failed and exited with 2 during

Tags: go, travis-ci, hugo

I am building websites with `Hugo` and deploying using `Travis-Ci`. Recently (about within 3 days) an error occurred:

```
$ go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo
# github.com/gohugoio/hugo/tpl/internal/go_templates/fmtsort
../../gohugoio/hugo/tpl/internal/go_templates/fmtsort/sort.go:58:18: mapValue.MapRange undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method MapRange)
The command "go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

Since the code errored at `go get` line, I think it must be caused by some updates by `Hugo`.

.travis.yml

```yaml
sudo: false

language: go

git:
  depth: 1

install: 
  - go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo

script:
  - git submodule init
  - git submodule update
  - hugo

  # Deploy to GitHub pages
deploy:
  provider: pages
  skip_cleanup: true
  github_token: $GITHUB_TOKEN
  local_dir: public
  on:
    branch: master
```

Comment: I just executed `go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo` and had no problem. It installed version v0.61.0. Could you try again in case this was a transient error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since Hugo 0.48, Hugo uses the Go Modules support built into Go 1.11 to build.

- docker run -it golang:1.10 
  root@2598ed7e489d: go get github.com/gohugoio/hugo 
  src/github.com/gohugoio/hugo/tpl/internal/go_templates/fmtsort/sort.go:58:18: mapValue.MapRange undefined (type reflect.Value has no field or method MapRange)
- docker run -it golang:1.11
  root@07e6e634656a: go get https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo
  will not return any error

> using go versions > 1.11 will not cause this issue.
>   In example 1,similar error is there.
>   In example 2,it is installed successfully.